# Connect from server 1 to server 2 using ibm mq series

Tags: java, queue, microservices, load-balancing, ibm-mq

I am connecting from server 1 to server 2 using ibm mq series(single queue manager group) using single subnet NAT ip address. Destination of server 2 is single ip address point. Problem is: whenever i connect different custodian data(client data) to upload data and whenever server restart happens on one custodian point, other custodian client resets and not able to connect to server2 ip address.
Solution i have attempted: instead of ibm mq series and regular c# code, using combination of microservices with java8 parallel processing and Apache Kafka to render parallel threads to connect with single nat ip subnet, so that none of the custodian codes get resetted.is this solution correct? But the destination server is giving single ip address point to connect for n custodians. Is there something i can do in nat gateway to parallel render data to destination IP address? Please help me with my solution.will be happy to help with any info.

Comment: Maybe a picture would help illustrate your environment?

Comment: I don't hv a figure. But essentially its like 2 server clients connecting to one destination IP address by way of message queue and one nat ip subnet point.

Comment: Do you have any TCP/IP error codes to help explain the problem you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear and then you go off on a tangent about your solution which again is not clear and appears to be creating an overly complex system.

So, let me guess what your setup is:

- Server 1 has an IBM MQ client running a C# .NET application. Is this correct?  If so, what version is the IBM MQ Client software?  i.e. 9.1.0.9
- Server 2 is running IBM MQ queue manager.  Is this correct?  If so, what version is the IBM MQ Server software? i.e. 9.2.0.4  Use the ***dspmqver*** command to get this information.

If the above is correct then it is pretty much a basic IBM MQ environment.

So, when your application has this issue, MQ would have thrown an ***MQException***.  What was the Completion Code and Reason Code?  The reason code would probably been one of the following

- 2009 [MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN]
- 2059 [MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE]
- 2538 [MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE]

What did your application do when it received the MQException?  Crash or die or loop forever?

Did you add reconnection login to your code to reconnect to the queue manager after the failure?

Comment: The exception is 2538 host not available exception on one of the member codes and other member code was running fine. But after 20 minutes, host not available was available again. This problem because both sync threads hitting same destination ip instead of load balanced server. It is causing 20 mins of inactivity, wherein expectation is to run smoothly without waiting to reconnect. Yes reconnection login is added. Application keeps looping and connects after some time

Comment: I have my reconnection logic is set to 60 seconds.  20 minutes is way, way too long.  You should have developers fix the code.

Comment: Hi @roger, I am more intrested about knowing how to load balance to single destination ip from you? It’s essentially two client nodes to single destination ip. How to load balance it?

Comment: I have another question here. If server connected to router using natted ips den restarting server, will the natted ips on router remain same r not? If not wen it will change?

Comment: I don't understand your comments.  Are you talking about MQ Clustering?

Comment: There are plenty of software solutions that will manage IPs, servers and MQ.  You can use Google to find that info.

Comment: for the first question,it’s just any server to any server communicating through jms server

Comment: for the second question, yes I am talking about mq series. Is there a possibility to keep natted ips same. Ok I will check internet for the same